# get value for calendar htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, calendar

```
example.com/calendar/2014/4/27 <- i wan to like this from this link example.com/calendar/load.php?year=2014&month=4&date=27
```

i tried to do this. but its not work.. i cant fix it.
that links also want like this

this link also want to work

> example.com/calendar/2014
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/4
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/4/27

i tried to like do this.. here my htaccess code

/calendar/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendar/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]


RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
```

plzz help me to this work.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in `/calendar/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendar/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: friend do u know about seo?

Comment: I know little... but you should worry abt it too much as long as you don't have duplicate content and have links with some descriptive text (like URL of this question on SO)

Comment: plz help me for this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320210/get-value-with-calendar-and-pagination-htaccess

Comment: plzz help me for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789858/mobile-redirect-to-desktop-version-using-htaccess