# get value with calendar and pagination htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, calendar, pagination

i want to add pagination for htaccess with like this. so i put examples. bottom has my htaccess code. so how to fix it to like this. help me to this post. thanks.

> example.com/calendar/2014/page/2 <- example.com/calendar/load.php?year=2014&page=2
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/4/page/2 <- example.com/calendar/load.php?year=2014&month=4&page=2
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/4/27/page/2 <- example.com/calendar/load.php?year=2014&month=4&date=27&page=2

here my htaccess code

/calendar/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendar/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendar/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]   
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&p=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&p=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3&p=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: page count should be available as `$_GET['page']`

Comment: plz help me for this one

Comment: in your question you wrote: `example.com/calendar/2014/page/2 <- example.com/calendar/load.php?year=2014&page=2`. If your URL is different than provide it here.

Comment: i want like this `/page/2` but on get php code its like this `&p=2`