# Mobile Redirect to desktop version using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, cookies

I have a website called

```
www.example.com
```

I have a mobile website called

```
m.example.com
```

firstly i want to redirect automatically from desktop version to mobile site (if it is mobile only.. i want to detect all mobile versions)

then I want to use an htaccess to automatically redirect the main website URL to the mobile version..
However, there is a link on the mobile version that points back to the main website called

`www.example.com/?nm=1`   (`nm` mean `nomobile`)

i want to set cookie for this one.. `(redirect to desktop site from mobile site)`

if user come again after passing time ago.. i want to check hv cookie.. `(check www.example.com/?nm=1 set cookie earlier)` if havent cookie automatically redirect to mobile version... if have cookie want to stay in desktop version.

How can I accomplish this via `htaccess` without JavaSCript.

Comment: It will be better to divide this long question into multiple small questions.

Comment: Part of this was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20820566/2209007) solves part of the problem for you. Just like that answer, I am not going to suggest a list with user-agents for you. Find a list that is suitable for you, and put it in the rule. The types of mobile devices, browsers in mobile devices etc is ever-changing, and this answer would be out-dated before I even posted it. You need to adapt that rule a little to prevent it from matching if the cookie "nomobile" is set to "1". You need a rule that sees the "nm=1" in the url and sets the cookie. You probably also want some kind of reset for that oookie, which I labeled "nm=0".

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nm=1
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=nomobile:1:localhost:10000]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nm=0
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=nomobile:0:localhost:10000]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(user-agent1|user-agent2|user-agent3|etc)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !nomobile=1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please check [the documentation for cookies](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) for the correct usage of the CO-flag on your specific site. The code above is not tested, but in theory it should work.